# Resolved package not found

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, pytorch

When I try to execute `conda env create -f virtual_platform_windows.yml`
It shows

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - pytorch==0.1.12=py35_0.1.12cu80
```

I tried installing pytorch for windows and error still comes.How to solve this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open: virtual_platform_windows.yml in Notepad
- Delete: - pytorch=0.1.12=py35_0.1.12cu80
- Delete: - torch==0.1.12
- Save

Using Anaconda prompt:

Execute the code: `conda env create -f virtual_platform_windows.yml`

Activate virtual environment: source activate virtual_platform

Install Pytorch seperately with `conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80`

Copy haas files into script directory

Answer (score 0):

Packages and anaconda version are updated now. so pytorch version 0.1.12 no longer available to download. It becomes old version now. But still I manage to download all these files. Please follow the following steps:

**step 1**: Download anaconda (Latest version) or Update anaconda by *conda update -n base conda.*

**step 2**: Copy and paste the following commands in anaconda prompt and wait 
for downloading.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg 
conda install -c anaconda freetype    
conda install -c menpo imageio     
conda install -c anaconda libtiff     
conda install -c conda-forge olefile    
conda install -c anaconda pillow    
conda install -c peterjc123 vc    
conda install -c anaconda alabaster     
conda install -c anaconda astroid     
conda install -c patrickfuller openbabel     
conda install -c anaconda babel     
conda install -c conda-forge bleach     
conda install -c anaconda certifi     
conda install -c anaconda cffi     
conda install -c anaconda chardet     
conda install -c anaconda colorama     
conda install -c anaconda decorator     
conda install -c anaconda docutils     
conda install -c conda-forge entrypoints     
conda install -c anaconda html5lib     
conda install -c conda-forge icu     
conda install -c anaconda imagesize    
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel     
conda install -c anaconda ipython     
conda install -c anaconda ipython_genutils     
conda install -c anaconda isort     
conda install -c conda-forge jedi     
conda install -c anaconda jinja2     
conda install -c slobodan image     
conda install -c anaconda scikit-image     
conda install -c anaconda jpeg     
conda install -c conda-forge jsonschema     
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_client     
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_core     
conda install -c anaconda lazy-object-proxy     
conda install -c anaconda libpng     
conda install -c conda-forge markupsafe     
conda install -c conda-forge mistune     
conda install -c anaconda mkl     
conda install -c anaconda nbconvert     
conda install -c anaconda nbformat     
conda install -c anaconda numpy     
conda install -c anaconda numpydoc     
conda install -c anaconda openssl     
conda install -c intel pandocfilters     
conda install -c intel path.py     
conda install -c anaconda pickleshare     
conda install -c anaconda pip     
conda install -c anaconda prompt_toolkit     
conda install -c anaconda psutil     
conda install -c conda-forge pycodestyle     
conda install -c conda-forge pycparser     
conda install -c anaconda pyflakes     
conda install -c anaconda pygments     
conda install -c anaconda pylint     
conda install -c anaconda pyqt     
conda install -c anaconda python     
conda install -c conda-forge python-dateutil     
conda install -c anaconda pytz     
conda install -c anaconda pyzmq     
conda install -c anaconda qt     
conda install -c anaconda qtawesome     
conda install -c anaconda qtconsole     
conda install -c anaconda qtpy     
conda install -c conda-forge requests     
conda install -c anaconda rope     
conda install -c anaconda setuptools     
conda install -c conda-forge simplegeneric     
conda install -c anaconda singledispatch     
conda install -c anaconda sip     
conda install -c conda-forge six     
conda install -c anaconda snowballstemmer     
conda install -c anaconda sphinx     
conda install -c anaconda sphinxcontrib     
conda install -c conda-forge sphinxcontrib-websupport     
conda install -c anaconda spyder     
conda install -c anaconda testpath     
conda install -c anaconda tornado     
conda install -c intel traitlets     
conda install -c intel vs2015_runtime     
conda install -c conda-forge wcwidth     
conda install -c anaconda wheel     
conda install -c anaconda win_unicode_console     
conda install -c conda-forge wincertstore     
conda install -c conda-forge wrapt     
conda install -c anaconda zlib     
conda install -c menpo opencv3     
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch     
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

**step 3**: If any of the above command is not working then check for the updated conda installation for that specific command in anaconda website or just type that command on google.com.

Answer (score 0):

in mycase the error came because of version of python.i tried to install imutils package through anakonda promt.but it showed the error "ResolvePackageNotFound"

try this commands:

//you can specify what ever version you want.here iam creating environment with the name "myenvironment" using the python version 3.9.7

conda create --name myenvironment python=3.9.7

activate myenvironment

//now try to install what ever package you want.iam installing imutils package.

conda install -c conda-forge imutils